# Moving through history of commands on command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history

I used to use <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to move through the history of commands.
Then, a few days later it changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>.
Now this also doesn't work to move through the history of commands entered.

How can I view all these settings or change it?
I tried to see the terminal setting by giving the command `stty` but it was of no help.
I searched through Google and found something called `bindkey`. I hope I am moving in the right direction.

I am not the root user, anyway I would like to know more about this even if could do nothing about it.

**KORN SHELL**

```
**OS Info :**
rcihp145 :/home/msingh2> uname -a
HP-UX rcihp145 B.11.23 U 9000/800 3683851961 unlimited-user license
```

Comment: If your shell behavior is changing, my guess is that your admin is making changes to the default shell profile /etc/profile. You should contact the admin and ask. If you changed something, anything, you need to describe the change in your question. Please add distro and terminal used too.

Comment: hmm..i havnt done any changes, perhaps they are done by admin then

Comment: `set -o emacs` is the setting for up/down ctrl-p/ctrl-n but whether the up/down works or not can be changed by .Xresources settings for xterm. Again, if this worked, and then stopped working, something was changed. The [xterm faq](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html) has the settings for arrow keys (and many others)

Comment: @bdowning A system administrator that would change these kind of settings on a regular basic would be a very lousy admin.

Comment: @Bernhard agreed!

Comment: @munish I didn't think I'd solved your problem. The thing is, it's difficult to say more without knowing more about your setup, especially knowing what you were running the previous times. Do you have a `~/.kshrc`? Would it be possible that you were running a different shell (bash, csh, …) the last time? How did you get that “KORN SHELL” information, what does `echo ${.sh.version}` show?

Comment: I just DID this `rcihp145:qa1wrk98:/qa1users1/rgs/test/qa1wrk98>echo $SHELL` and got
`/usr/bin/ksh`  even though your answer did not solved my problem. I think it gave me where and what to look for depending upon the shell.I have got to do more serach and reading based on these and find out the possiblities              There is no kshrc here  but i could see .cshrc,.exrc,.login and `echo ${.sh.version}` din't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [ksh (the Korn shell)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell). This shell is fairly primitive in terms of command line capabilities, but do check the “key bindings” or “line editing” section to see what your version of ksh can do.

History navigation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> works in all ksh versions that I know of. They might be disabled in a configuration file; look in `~/.kshrc` to see what has been configured.

There are shells with better and more configurable line edition capabilities: [zsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh) and the more popular but less powerful [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). `bindkey` is a zsh command, and `bind` is its bash equivalent.